# Is Facebook chat API going away?

Tags: facebook-chat

Is Facebook Chat API going away? [This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), at the bottom, says
`The Chat/XMPP service and API, located at chat.facebook.com, will not be available once 1.0 is deprecated.`
That is the only place a reference to `chat` is being made. I ask as I was hoping to build an app for facebook chat and was reading up on its API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is going away without any replacement.

Comment: So, does that mean the facebook chat will be dead too? I do not use facebook much at all so please bear with me.

Comment: U can, still, use facebook chat on facebook.com, or fb messeger. But the programmers cannot create chat applications which connect with facebook chat. Also, chat with facebook friends in outlook online will be not available.
So, that's all I can say, after this April, facebook chat, only available on facebook.com, and fb messenger.